# Ecto: schemaless many_to_many with unique constraint

Tags: many-to-many, elixir, ecto

What is the right wait to propagate error from Postgres, when inserting duplicate element into `many-to-many` relation defined using `table` that has `unique_index`:

```
schema "books" do
  ...
  many_to_many :authors, Author, join_through: "books_authors"
end

preload(book, :authors)
|> change
|> put_assoc(:authors, authors)
|> unique_constraint(:authors, name: :books_authors_book_id_author_id_index)
```

So this throws the error:

```
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR (unique_violation): duplicate key value violates unique constraint "books_authors_book_id_author_id_index"
```

Possible solution is to use `BookAuthor` schema, but is there way to make it work in schemaless fashion?